# $K^{\text{quad}}$ and complex conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a field that maps to itself under complex conjugation. Prove that $K^{\text{quad}}\subset\mathbb{C}$ also maps to itself under complex conjugation.

$K^{\text{quad}}$ is defined as: $K^{\text{quad}}=\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}K_i$, where $K_0=K$ and $K_i=K_{i-1}(\sqrt{K_{i-1}})$ for $i\geq 1$.
$K(\sqrt{K})$ is defined as the subfield $K(S)\subset\overline{K}$ generated by the set $S=\{w\in\overline{K}|w^2\in K\}$ (the set of square roots of elements of $K$).

Any hints on how to attack this?

Comment: What is $K^\text{quad}$? The squares in $K$?

Comment: I edited the question with the relevant definitions.

Comment: Please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Didn't you try induction?

Comment: Here, if $f$ denotes the complex conjugation, the induction hypothesis is that $f(\bigcup_{i=0}^{n} K_i)=\bigcup_{i=0}^{n} K_i$. Then you have to prove that $f(\bigcup_{i=0}^{n+1} K_i)=\bigcup_{i=0}^{n+1} K_i=\bigcup_{i=0}^{n} K_i\cup K_{n+1}$. Now, $K_{n+1}=K_n(S)$, with $S=\{w\in\mathbb{C}|w^2\in K_n\}$. Therefore it would be enough to prove that $f(w)\in S\ \forall w\in S$, but I don't really see how.

Comment: Your induction is a good start. Note that $K_n = \bigcup_{i=0}^n K_i$. Now, take any $\alpha\in K_{n+1}$. Then $\alpha$ is a root of some polynomial $g(x)=x^2-k$, for $k\in K_n$. Now, I claim $\overline{\alpha}$ is a root of $h(x)=x^2-\overline{k}$, where $\overline{k}$ also lies in $K_n$ by our induction assumption.

Indeed, we see that $h(\overline{\alpha})=(\overline{\alpha})^2-\overline{k} = \overline{\alpha^2}-\overline{k} = \overline{\alpha^2-k}=\overline{g(\alpha)} = 0.$
Then by definition of $K_{n+1}$, we see that $\overline{\alpha}\in K_{n+1}$.